# Hashtag search in facebook Error :(#11) Post search has been deprecated

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, hashtag

This is **Bundle identifier com.facebook.FBLoginCustomUISample** then it is work fine.
    But when i change **Bundle identifier com.photosnapy.iphone** it will give error.
    error ={
        code = 11;
        message = "(#11) Post search has been deprecated";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
    https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3D%2523app&version=v1.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes post search have been deprecated. If you app was active before 4/30/2014 you can use API v1.0 until 4/30/2015. Otherwise you have to use API v2.0 which don't have post search

Comment: hello sir i use API v1.0. it work on Bundle identifier com.facebook.FBLoginCustomUISample fine But not work in Bundle identifier com.photosnapy.iphone

Comment: And your app was active before 4/30/2014?

Comment: Then you can't use API v1.0.

Comment: com.photosnapy.iphone is Bunddle Id is new and i think  create before 4/30/2014 com.facebook.FBLoginCustomUISample

Comment: The bundle id doesn't matter. What is the Facebook App ID and when was it created?

Comment: Read answer. If your app was active before 4/30/2014 you can use post search until 4/30/2015. Otherwise you can't

Comment: Any alternative option for get hashtag search?

Comment: No, there is not. I would suggest that you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score -1):

If you have a reasonable reason, you can contact Facebook, maybe they will provide a proper solution for you